# Localhost shows on Lan, but does not open websites

Tags: networking, localhost, wamp, lan

I have successfully enabled Localhost directory from a main pc to other pcs on lan.
Also phpmyadmin is accessible for these other machines.

Although, when I click on a website from the localhost list, the browser says: Internet Connection Error.

It's not the browser, as I've tried Firefox, Chrome and Opera.
Also localhost keeps working normally on the main pc.

I've put this on **httpd.conf**:

```
<Directory "C:/wamp64/www/">
    Require ip 192.168.0
</Directory>
```

And my **phpmyadmin.conf** looks like this:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.5.2/"

<Directory "C:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.5.2/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.0
# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: probably not correct site for this, but localhost (127.0.0.1 | ::1 ) is only available from your computer and refers to your current computer. accessing it on other computers will result it trying to connect the webserver that doesn't appear to be running on them.  Try accessing it via the IP assigned to your computer `192.168.0.x` and see if that works.  This assumes that apache is listening on `0.0.0.0` (all ips) or your ip address, and not just localhost

Comment: I do have access to the localhost directory typing the IP number. The problem is that when I click on any site directory inside localhost, the error is Internet Connection Error.

Comment: what is the url that you are clicking on (also disable friendly error messages, so you can see the real error as opposed to didn't work ones that windows appears to generate)

Comment: You cannot use the WAMPServer home page when connected from another PC. All the links are based on `localhost` which means when you click a link it looks on the PC you are sitting at for a web server and not the other PC that is running WAMPServer(Apache)

Comment: I've got it working. I did the same configurations I mentioned above on an other pc and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration in my question is correct. It works perfectly on another pc. Ther must be some sharing issues on the first pc I've tried.